# Derivative of a complex conjugate

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I anticipate that this is a stupid question, but suppose $c \in C$. What is $\frac{\partial c^{*}}{\partial c}$? I've been trying and failing for about an hour to figure it out from the definition of the derivative. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Separate c into real and imaginary parts. The derivative will not be analytic. For more information, you might want to look up Cauchy Riemann Equations.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of >.<. Thanks (Y)